# How can I evaluate a large number of boolean ANDs quickly?

Tags: c, algorithm, boolean

I need to run millions of queries of the following kind.

Each input consists of a small collection (<100) of boolean vectors of various sizes (<20000 elements), with each having a few 1s and many 0s :

```
A = [ 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... ]
B = [ 0 0 0 0 1 0 ... ]
...
```

I also have many (>20000) boolean AND expressions.  These expressions are constant for all queries.

```
S[1] = A[10] AND B[52] AND F[15] AND U[2]
S[2] = I[8] AND Z[4]
...
```

Each expression can reference zero or one element from each vector.  Variables rarely appear in more than one expression.  For each query, output is the set of true expressions.

What's a good algorithm to compute the queries quickly, preferably more quickly than evaluating each expression in order?  The algorithm needs to run once for each input, and there are millions of inputs to run on, so speed is important.  Since the expressions are constant, I can optimize them ahead of time.  I'm working with C.

Comment: Such approaches tend to hide the actual problem. Perhaps you have a wrong view on the actual problem? However, you could use a variable length array for each term pointing to the required fields.

Comment: The expressions give you direct indexes into the arrays, right? It's just a constant direct memory lookup.  Just and together those memory locations.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm with @greybeard. I don't get *"The algorithm needs to run once for each input value, and there are millions of input values."* Do you mean you have more than one set of "<100 vectors"?

Comment: I meant to say that each input consists of several vectors, and I need to run on millions of such inputs.  Does that explain it better?

Comment: please post the code you have tried so far.  then post the problem(s) you found with the code you posted.   stackoverflow is for 1) determining why code does not compile+how to fix it and 2) determining why the output is not what is expected+how to fix it.

Comment: @BrandonYates, I am currently iterating over my rules and anding together the memory locations.  This approach is too slow and I'm looking for a faster way to do it.

Comment: you have not shown any code so it is a bit difficult to help you since we may misunderstand the problem.  e.g. how do you store the A,B in memory, int arrays?

Comment: Your best bets may be: 1) present the frame this is used in - I'm with @Olaf in suspecting a solution to the partial problem presented not necessarily being part of a good solution. 2) find a representation for the variable sized boolean vectors lending itself to fast evaluation. 3) choose a runtime environment and do timings, preferably using "real" input data and ignoring anything under five seconds.

Comment: @greybeard, Thanks for the input.  I've re-worded the question similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using *lots* of data.  It's a guess, but I'd say you'll get optimal behavior by preprocessing your expressions into cache optimal passes.  Consider the two expressions given:

```
S[1] = A[10] AND B[52] AND F[15] AND U[2]
S[2] = I[8] AND Z[4]
```

rewrite these as:

```
S[1] = 1;
S[1] &= A[10];
S[1] &= B[52];
S[1] &= F[15];
S[1] &= U[2];

S[2] = 1;
S[2] &= I[8];
S[2] &= Z[4];
```

Then sort all of the expressions together to create one long list of operations:

```
S[1] = 1;
S[2] = 1;

S[1] &= A[10];
S[1] &= B[52];
S[1] &= F[15];
S[2] &= I[8];
S[1] &= U[2];
S[2] &= Z[4];
```

Consider the size of the machine cache on hand.  We want all of the input vectors in cache.  That probably can't happen so we know we will be pulling the input vectors and the result vectors in and out of memory multiple times.  We want to partition the available machine cache into three parts: input vector chunk, result vector chunk, and some working space (where our current list of operations will be pulled from).

Now, walk the list of expressions pulling out expressions that fall into the A-I and S[1]-S[400] range.  Then walk again pulling J-T (or whatever fits in cache) and pull those operations next, once you get to the end of the operations list repeat for s[401]-s[800].  This is the final order of execution for the operations.  Note that this can be parallelized without contention across the S bands.

The down side is that you do not get the early out behavior.  The upside is you only have cache failures as you transition blocks of computation.  For such a large data set I suspect this (and the elimination of all branching) will overwhelm the early out advantage.

If you still want to try to use the early out optimization you *can* it is just harder to implement.  Consider: once you have your cache bracket A-I & S[1]-s[400], and you have created a list of operations across that bracket:

```
S[1] &= A[10];
S[1] &= B[52];
S[1] &= F[15];
S[2] &= I[8];
```

You can then reorder the operations to group them by S[x] (which this example already was).  Now if you find A[10] is false you can "early out" to the S[2] block.  As far as how to implement this?  Well, your operations now need to know how many to skip forward from the current operation:

```
Operation[x  ] => (S[1] &= A[10], on false, x+=3)
Operation[x+1] => (S[1] &= B[52], on false, x+=2)
Operation[x+2] => (S[1] &= F[15], on false, x+=1)
Operation[x+3] => (S[2] &= I[8]...
```

Again, I suspect simply adding the branching in will be slower than just performing all of the other work.  This is not a full early out process since the when you move to the next input block chunk you'll have to reinspect each S[x] value accessed to determine if it has already failed and should be skipped.

Answer (score 5):

Return early. As soon as you find a false boolean, you know that the `and` expression will return `false`, so don't check the rest.

In C, you get this behavior by default in hardcoded boolean expressions:

```
(A[10] && B[52] && F[15] && U[2])
```

Depending on how predictable the inputs are, you might be able to get a lot of performance out of ranking each expression's variables per likelihood of being false, and reordering the expression from most likely to less likely.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert your inputs to packed form (list of indexes for non-zero elements). To make whole approach quicker than evaluating each expression in order, you need to process several elements at once, using either compiler intrinsics of bit twiddling (assuming that each input boolean occupies just one byte, or even better one bit).
2. Pre-process 'AND' expressions to arrays mapping indexes from packed input arrays to the expression to which it belongs. (But if some variable appears in more than one expression, it will require some special handling).
3. Initialize counters for expressions to 0.
4. Read packed input arrays and increment counters for corresponding expressions.
5. Expressions having counter equal to their number of terms are 'true', others are 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you preprocess the expressions to produce:

1. a list for each variable containing the expressions with that variable (i.e. the list for A10 would be [S1,any other expressions with A10])
2. a count for each expression of the number of variables in that expression (i.e. the count for S1 would be 4)

Then for each input:

1. Initialise a count for each expression to the total number of variables in that expression
2. Loop over all sparse set bits in the input and for each input decrement the count for all expressions containing that bit
3. Return all expressions where the count reached 0.

Comment: Great "out of the box" thinking. With `Variables rarely appear in more than one expression`, I'd expect performance gains from the conversion of two nested loops to two sequential loops.